# Squareup Payment Gateway Api Bad Request 400

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, payment-gateway, bad-request

1. This is where I get the bad request

   ```
   public void OnPost(string nonce)
   {
       TransactionsApi transactionsApi = new TransactionsApi();
       string uuid = NewIdempotencyKey();
       Money amount = new Money(1, Money.CurrencyEnum.USD);
       ChargeRequest body = new ChargeRequest(AmountMoney: amount, IdempotencyKey: uuid, CardNonce: nonce);

       try
       {
   ```
2. I get the bad request in this line of code.

   ```
           var response = transactionsApi.Charge(LocationId, body);
           this.ResultMessage = "Transaction complete! " + response.ToJson();
       }
       catch (ApiException e)
       {
           this.ResultMessage = e.Message;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Send your `transactionsApi.Charge` prototype, please and also `LocationId`. What's `LocationId` value?

Comment: Are you sure it's possible to concatenate `string` and `response.ToJson()` ?

Comment: transactionsApi.Charge is in the Square.Connect.Api library dll

Comment: public ChargeResponse Charge(string locationId, ChargeRequest body);

Comment: `response.ToJson()` returns `string` or `Json` object or somthing else?

Comment: Exception occurs in this line
var response = transactionsApi.Charge(LocationId, body);

does not matter if its possible or not to concatenate string and response.ToJson()

Comment: value of location id is "CBASEAI_3qCTY_WldyqqpTMfWLEgAQ"
but this value works with the other solution ....

Comment: Ok, and what is `transactionsApi` exactly? You want to call another API or it's just a method call?